# Change button if it is in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make two buttons show, only if it is in an existing list. But so far it has not succeeded yet.

I want a certain button to show if it is in this list declared in the **Wishlist Controller**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IQueryable<WishlistModel> model = null;
    int wishlist_id = Check();

    if (wishlist_id != 0)
    {
        var WishLines = _context.WishLines.Where(l => l.Wishmain_id == wishlist_id).ToList();
        if (WishLines.Count() > 0)
        {
            model = from wishlines in _context.WishLines
                    join items in _context.Items on wishlines.itm_id equals items.id
                    join wishmain in _context.WishMains on wishlines.Wishmain_id equals wishmain.id
                    where wishlines.Wishmain_id == wishlist_id
                    select new WishlistModel
                    {
                        description = items.description,
                        price = items.price,
                        ordline_id = wishlines.id,
                        photo_url = items.photo_url,
                        item_id = items.id
                    };
            ViewBag.model_for_view = model;
            return View(model.ToList());
        }
    }
    ViewBag.model_for_view = model;
    return View();
}
```

And a certain button to show when it's not in the list

I tried it this way on the view:

```
@{
    WishLines wishLine = new WishLines();
    bool check = wishLine.itm_id == item.id;

    if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        if (check == true)
        {
            <a>Remove from favorites list</a>
        }
        else
        {
            <a>Add to favorites list</a>
        }
    }
}
```

But this will only show the `else` option, even if it is in the list.

How can I make it on the view that it shows the right button?

Comment: `item.id` is from the model on the view, `@model IEnumerable<bytme.Models.Item>` and `wishLine.itm_id` is from the model WishLines

Comment: So you create an empty WishLines object and are surprised that itm_id doesn't match to anything?

Comment: I changed my code to inherit a ViewBag from the controller to inherit the WishLines itm_id. Thank you all who made me see my error! Creating an empty WishLines is not the way to retrieve an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WishLines wishLine = new WishLines();
```

You are initializing a new WishLines so its itm_id will never be equals to item.id

Answer (score 2):

wishLine is new. So wishLine.itm_id is always 0 .

```
WishLines wishLine = new WishLines(); // wishLine is new
bool check = wishLine.itm_id == item.id; // 0 == item.id returns false
```